# Zorn vector-matrix description of octonion multiplication

Tags: nonassociative-algebras

[Zorn's vector-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion#Zorn%27s_vector-matrix_algebra) are a way to describe [split octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion) by treating them as matrices

$$ \begin{bmatrix}a & \mathbf v\\ \mathbf w & b\end{bmatrix} $$

where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  The multiplication of split octonions is then given by

$$ \begin{bmatrix}a & \mathbf v\\ \mathbf w & b\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a' & \mathbf v'\\ \mathbf w' & b'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}aa' + \mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w' & a\mathbf v' + b'\mathbf v + \mathbf w \times \mathbf w'\\ a'\mathbf w + b\mathbf w' - \mathbf v\times\mathbf v'  & bb' + \mathbf v'\cdot\mathbf w \end{bmatrix} $$

I think there's a similar formula that describes the multiplication of *ordinary* octonions: to get it, we probably just change some signs above.   Does anyone know this formula, or a reference to it?

I should probably work it out myself, but I feel someone must have already have written it down.

Answer (score 3):

I know of two vector-matrix-like representations of the octonions, but unfortunately none of them rely on changing the multiplication.

One of them is to realize the octonions as a subalgebra of the [complex octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioctonion) $\mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{O}$ (this is a split algebra since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, and thus can be identified with Zorn's algebra with complex entries). The realization of $\mathbb{O} \subset \mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{O}$ is given by vector-matrices of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & \mathbf{v} \\ -\bar{\mathbf{v}} & \bar{a} \end{pmatrix},$$

where $a$ and the components of $\mathbf{v}$ are now complex numbers, and the bar denotes conjugation. The multiplication is formally the same. This is analogous to the known representation of quaternions as ordinary $2\times 2$ complex matrices of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -\bar{b} & \bar{a} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Intuitively, this is similar to the idea of finding the compact Lie groups inside the complex Lie groups by imposing some "unitarity condition" (in this case the condition is that $M M^{\dagger}$ be a real multiple of the identity, where $\dagger$ denotes the usual Hermitian conjugation, extended in the obvious way to vector-matrices).

---

The other way is to realize $\mathbb{O}$ inside the split-sedenions (the [Cayley-Dickson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) doubling of the split-octonions). These are isomorphic to vector-matrices where the vectors are $7$-dimensional:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & \mathbf{V} \\ \mathbf{W} & b \end{pmatrix},$$

where I use uppercase to denote seven-dimensional vectors. The multiplication is again given by the same formula, except that now $\times$ is the [seven-dimensional cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product). (I don't know of a reference for this, but it's easy to find an explicit isomorphism). The subalgebra given by

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & \mathbf{V} \\ -\mathbf{V} & a \end{pmatrix}$$

is then isomorphic to $\mathbb{O}$, as can be explicitly checked. There are analogous representations of quaternions and complex numbers given by

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & \mathbf{v} \\ -\mathbf{v} & a \end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}$$

respectively (the latter is well-known).

This representation doesn't require the use of complex entries, though on the other hand it feels a bit circular to me, since the 7D cross product is already closely related to octonions; if you "know" one you already "know" the other in some sense.

---

I don't know if there is a natural way to arrive at the octonions by modifying only the multiplication formula instead of the vector-matrices themselves, but it strikes me as somewhat unlikely. This would be akin to realizing the quaternions as $2\times 2$ real matrices with a modified multiplication. If there is some way of doing it, it would probably be more involved than a change of signs.

Comment: Thanks!  Since we've got the split octonions described using vector-matrices with a weird multiplication formula, and the multiplication of octonions only differs from that of split octonions by a bunch of signs, I was hoping we can just change some signs in that formula.  But maybe we can't.  Going to the bioctonions (complexified octonions) and then finding the octonions as a subalgebra in there is a nice fallback strategy.